# При создании excel файла импортирует туда всю html страницу

Tags: php, excel, битрикс

Доброго времени суток, знатоки!

Сразу оговорюсь, что сайт пишу на данный момент на битриксе. Мне нужно написать скрипт на генерацию счета по оплате в формате xls. Столкнулся с проблемой в неожиданном месте. Когда файл уже сформирован и мне нужно его отдать в excel и клиенту на скачивание - в файл импортируется весь текст со станицы, где вызывается скрипт.

Пробовал гуглить, пробовал менять заголовки - ничего не помогает. Если импортировать в ворд или scv - тот же результат. Когда делал подобное на фреймворке - не сталкивался с подобным. Может, кто-нибудь знает, в чем проблема?

Comment: В том, что при отдаче файла почему-то генерируется страница целиком и попадает в вывод (в начало, конец или середину excel-файла).

Comment: Вот тут и непонятно, где это происходит. Выводить пытался по-разному. И просто пустой файл пытался создать - все ранво туда пихает страницу. Проблему решил путем сохранения файла в папку и потом уже отдаю клиенту. Так все норм сохраняет. Но вопрос остается открытым: почему при прямой отдаче такая фигня происходит?